# How to update array in Database?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to update array in Codeigniter but but I can't figure out the syntax.

Error:
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 1525

```
    public function allowregis()
    {
    $data = $this->input->post();

    for($i= 0;$i < count($data["regis_id"]);$i++)
    {
        $allow[] = array('regis_id' => $data['regis_id'][$i],
                    'regis_status' => $data['regis_status'][$i],
                    'regis_approveresult' => $data['regis_approveresult'][$i],
        );
    }

        $this->db->update('register',$allow,'regis_id');
        redirect('/register/cheackactivityallow/');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error says, you're trying to update a field with an array value ( `$allow`) that is expecting a string to be passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add your update query inside the for loop.

```
public function allowregis()
{
$data = $this->input->post();

$allow = array();
for($i= 0;$i < count($data["regis_id"]);$i++)
{
    $allow[$i] = array('regis_id' => $data['regis_id'][$i],
                'regis_status' => $data['regis_status'][$i],
                'regis_approveresult' => $data['regis_approveresult'][$i],
    );
    $this->db->update('register',$allow[$i]);
}
    redirect('/register/cheackactivityallow/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the update_batch function of codeigniter for the desired result as you are sending a multi dimension array to the update function it will through a error.

[check here for batch update](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where#CI_DB_query_builder::update_batch)